# datepicker issue storing wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Using Datepicker I have 2 problems.

1) when the page loads I want the field to display todays date 01/10/2013. Instead it displays 01/01/0001...however if the user clicks on the field and the datepicker calendar appears, todays date will be highlighted on the calendar, why is it being high lighted on the calendar but displaying wrong date in the field

2)If the user selected a date from the datepicker it stores whatever date is selected plus an additional 2013....so user selects todays date, 01/10/20132013 will be stored in the field.

Any Help on how to resolve this. thanks guys

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDate, new { @class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value = Model.SelectedDate.HasValue ? Model.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty })

@using (Script.Foot())
    {
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(function () {
                var dates = $("#SelectedDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                })(todayDate);
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first point, you may try to initialize your datepicker removing the uppercase in `dd/MM/yyyy`. This should solve this matter : dd/mm/yyyy.

And for the second part, year format seems to be only `yy`. By adding twice "yy", the datepicker display twice "2013".

I hope this help.

EDIT #1

```
 $(function () {
        var dates = $("#SelectedDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        defaultDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

Comment: ok first off, thanks for the reply Eden....but my casing in dd/mm/yyyy are all lowercase. but for the second part i removed yy, and that seemed to resolve the issue about about the extra 2013, however when the user clicks on the field and the calendar displays it no longer selects todays date, it selects 01/01/0001, which is what it shows in the field??

Comment: at the end of this line, MM is NOT lowercase :@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDate, new { class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value = Model.SelectedDate.HasValue ? Model.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty })

Comment: apologies I was looking at: dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', but yeah thanks man...although one minor problem, when the page loads the field still displays 01/00/0001 (but if the user clicks on the field and the calendar displays, it highlights todays date, then if the user selects a date, it correctly shows what date was chosen. any idea as to why it is showing 01/00/0001 though? when i run it through debug mode i get an error with the (todaydate) inside the script tags saying JavaScript runtime error: 'todayDate' is undefined...could this be the problem.

Comment: I'am not sure about this var, but it seems you're right, it doesn't exist. I suggest you remove it, and try to force the datepicker to start with today's date (even if it is supposed to be the default date). Have a look at the FIRST EDIT from the answer.

Comment: thank you for all the help, much appreciated but this still hasnt resolved the issue. would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try $("#SelectedDate").datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date());